# Passing a file-like object to write() method of another file-like object

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip, pipeline

I am trying to get a large file from the web, and stream it directly into the zipfile writer provided by the `zipfile` module, something like:

```python
from urllib.request import urlopen
from zipfile import ZipFile

zip_file = ZipFile("/a/certain/local/zip/file.zip","a")
entry = zip_file.open("an.entry","w")
entry.write( urlopen("http://a.certain.file/on?the=web") )
```

Apparently, this doesn't work because `.write` accepts a `bytes` argument, not an I/O reader. However, since the file is rather large I don't want to load the whole file into RAM before compressing it.

The simple solution is to use bash (never really tried, could be wrong):

```bash
curl -s "http://a.certain.file/on?the=web" | zip -q /a/certain/local/zip/file.zip
```

but it wouldn't be a very elegant, nor convenient, thing to put a single line of bash in a Python script.

Another solution is to use `urllib.request.urlretrieve` to download the file and then pass the path to `zipfile.ZipFile.open`, but that way I would still have to wait for the download to complete, and besides that also consume a lot more disk I/O resource.

Is there a way, in Python, to directly pass the download stream to a zipfile writer, like the the bash pipeline above?

Comment: you have some alternatives like `gzopen` to create a .gz file.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I need an archive, so in that case I would need `tar` if I want to use `gzip`.

Comment: you can use `.read(size)` to get data in chunk

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre what is `gzopen`? Do you mean [`gzip.open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#gzip.open) or something else?

Comment: yes Gzip.open thats iy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`shutil.copyfileobj()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj) to efficiently copy data between file objects:

```
from shutil import copyfileobj

with ZipFile("/a/certain/local/zip/file.zip", "w") as zip_file:
    with zip_file.open("an.entry", "w") as entry:
        with urlopen("http://a.certain.file/on?the=web") as response:
            shutil.copyfileobj(response, entry)
```

This'll call `.read()` with a given chunksize on the source file object, then pass that chunk to the `.write()` method on the target file object.

If you are using Python 3.5 or older (where you can't yet directly write to a `ZipFile` member), your only option is to stream to a temporary file first:

```
from shutil import copyfileobj
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

with ZipFile("/a/certain/local/zip/file.zip", "w") as zip_file:
    with NamedTemporaryFile() as cache:
        with urlopen("http://a.certain.file/on?the=web") as response:
            shutil.copyfileobj(response, cache)
            cache.flush()
            zipfile.write('an.entry', cache.name)
```

Using a `NamedTemporaryFile()` like this only works on POSIX systems, on Windows, you can't open the same filename again, so you'd have to use a [`tempfile.mkstemp()` generated name](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkstemp), open the file from there, and use `try...finally` to clean up afterwards.

Comment: problem is that [zip_file.open()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.open) can be used only to read - `"r"`. And [ZipFile.write()](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write) expects only filename :(

Comment: @furas: I was looking at the [Python 3.6 revision](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.open).

Comment: @furas: For Python < 3.6, you'd have to add a `NamedTempFile()` in between, I fear.

Comment: Luckily I'm using Python 3.6. Just for the sake of understanding, doesn't copying to `cache` block until the download is complete?

Comment: @busukxuan: yes, the `copyfileobj()` call won't return until `response.read()` no longer produces data (and that data was written out to `cache`).